# What is pin goal strength for Hair Dynamics?

Tags: particles, hair

I thought for sure if I searched I'd see a description, but i don't see one so I thought i'd ask, for common answer vs a technical definition.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/hair/dynamics.html) describes it as:

> Spring stiffness of the vertex target position.

To my understanding, this is how much the hair wants to "spring" back into its initial/styled position. A lower value makes the hair looser and a higher value makes it stiffer.

This is something probably best understood by simply experimenting with the value and seeing how it affects the simulation (this description just comes from my own experience).

Comment: Sometimes, the blender manual manages to use the English language on every word, yet provide no information whatsoever except to its developers !  ;-)